# How can i tell if one joda-time DateTime object is within 4 hours of another?

Tags: java, jodatime

What's the best way to tell if one joda time DateTime object is within 4 hours of another if I don't know which object is earlier than the other?

The Joda Time Duration object seems to do this job well if I know that object A comes before object B, but since Duration is signed it doesn't seem to do what I want if I don't know the order.

Seems like there would be an easy way to do this, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the **[Hours](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html?org/joda/time/ReadablePeriod.html)** class for this:

```
Hours h = Hours.hoursBetween(date1, date2); 
int hours = h.getHours();
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I noticed a little caveat on this.  Scenario1: (time1 = 4:00:00)  and (time2 = 8:00:00).  This gives you 4 hours - no problem here.  However in Scenario2:  (time1 = 4:00:00) and (time2 = 8:30:00), you still get 4 hours when the time between is actually 4 hours and 30 minutes - which would be out of your timeframe.  You could potentially get an extra (unwanted) hour.

Comment: I noticed this question regarding elapsed time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time

Comment: Is there a way to find out if the current hour of the day falls between two given hours of the day? For e.g. 6 falls between 21 and 9, so the function should return true.

Comment: For sure there is. You could ask this as a separate question on SO along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the compareTo() method on the two DateTime objects to tell which one is earlier and then use Duration to see if they are within 4 hours.

Comment: Thanks mR_fr0g, that one also works fine of course, but again, seems a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if (Math.abs(new Duration(start, end).getStandardSeconds()) < 4 * 3600) {
  // blah blah blah
}
```