# How can I convert this date in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, date, date-format

I want to convert:

```
2010-03-15T16:34:46Z
```

into something like "5 hours ago"

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Are you open to using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time/2179831#2179831) for an example. Doing so using standard `java.util.Calendar` API would only lead to verbose code and headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) supports parsing from a user-defined format. See DateTimeFormatterBuilder and DateTimeBuilder.parseDateTime().

Once you have a DateTime, you can create a Duration or Period from that and the current time, and use another formatter to pretty-print. [See the PeriodFormatter example referenced by BalusC in comments above.]

Comment: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I know a plugin in Jquery for this : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/CuteTime

For Java i assume you will need to use your brain :) ( You can translate it to Java )

Answer (score 0):

```
     Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2010,Calendar.March,15, 16,34,46);
     calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR,-5);
```

Comment: You misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(
    Instant.parse( "2010-03-15T16:34:46Z" ) , 
    Instant.now() 
)     
.toHours()    // returns a `long` integer number. 
+ " hours ago"
```

> 5 hours ago

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

### `Instant`

Parse your input string. That string uses a format defined in the ISO 8601 standard. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2010-03-15T16:34:46Z" ) ;
```

Get our later moment.

```
Instant later = instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Let’s use an moment five hour later.

```
Instant later = instant.plus( 5L , ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;
```

### `Duration`

Represent elapsed time of hours-minutes-seconds with `Duration` class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( instant , later ) ;
```

If you want to report the entire elapsed time as one big number of hours, call [`Duration::toHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toHours()).

```
String output = d.toHoursPart() + " hours ago" ;
```

> 5 hours ago

In Java 9 and later, call `to…Part` to get each part of days, hours, minutes, seconds, nanoseconds. These methods were strangely missing in Java 8, but added in Java 9 and later.

```
long daysPart = d.toDaysPart() ;
int hoursPart = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutesPart = d.toMinutesPart() ;
String output = … ;  // Use the parts to generate your output.
```

### ISO 8601 duration

You may find the [ISO 8601 compliant string for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) generated by [`Duration::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString()) to be useful: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`

The `P` marks the beginning. The `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds.

So our example above for five hours would be:

> PT5H

Such strings can be parsed into `Duration` hours.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT5H" ) ;
```

Comment: Nice, thank you!  Should toHoursPart just be toHours?

Comment: @LouMorda If you want the entire duration as one big number of hours, call `Duration::toHours`. More likely, you will want the number of 24-hour generic days, and the hours, and the minutes, and perhaps seconds. If so, in that case do as I mentioned in the Answer, call `to…Part` methods for each of those parts. I will revise the text to make this more clear. Thanks for asking.