# How can I convert this string to a standard date in java?

Tags: java, datetime, time, date-format, simpledateformat

Earlier I posted the following question: [How can I convert this date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791984/how-can-i-convert-this-date-in-java)

But now I would like to know how I can convert this string into a date/time.

```
2010-03-15T16:34:46Z
```

For example: 03/15/10

**UPDATED:**

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yy 'at' HH:mm";
                Date date = new Date();
                try {
                    date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(q.getUpdated_at());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dateText.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy 'at' hh:mma").format(date));
```

Gives me a result like:

```
Mon Mar 15 16:34:50 MST 2010
```

How can I format it to be

```
03/15/10 at 4:34PM
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, you want to convert a date in *a **string** format* to a date in *another **string** format*. You have:

```
2010-03-15T16:34:46Z
```

and you want

```
03/15/10 at 4:34PM
```

You don't want to end up using [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object as you initially implied in your question. You also don't want to use its `toString()` since that returns a fixed format as definied in [its javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).

The answer of Bozho still applies. Use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). First, you need to *parse* the date in string format into a `Date` object so that you can *format* it back into another string format.

```
// First parse string in pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" to date object.
String dateString1 = "2010-03-15T16:34:46Z";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(dateString1);

// Then format date object to string in pattern "MM/dd/yy 'at' h:mma".
String dateString2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy 'at' h:mma").format(date);
System.out.println(dateString2); // 03/15/10 at 4:34PM
```

Answer (score 8):

Both [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) `DateTimeFormat` can parse this, using this pattern:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
```

For example:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(dateString);
```

And (joda-time):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(s);
```

**Update**

You have 2 date formats involved - one for *parsing* the input, and one for *formatting* the output. So:

```
dateText.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy 'at' hh:mma").format(date));
```

(Of course, for the sake of optimization, you can instantiate the `SimpleDateFormat` only once, and reuse it)

Comment: Almost there! How can I format it to be give my results as "3/15/10 at 7:43PM" -- I have updated my question with code.

Comment: According to the `SimpleDateFormat` link in the answer, pattern would then be `M/d/y 'at' H:mma`. Did you check the link?

Comment: I tried that, still no luck. Getting the same results. Check out the updated code in the question.

Comment: Follow up: I tried plugging in some of the sample patterns from the link, w/ no luck either.

Comment: @Bozho I'm not sure what you mean by "parse the date, and set the original string in the field." -- can you show me an example?

Comment: @Bozho `dateText.setText(q.getUpdated_at());` will just be: `2010-03-15T16:34:46Z` -- i want to be able to take `2010-03-15T16:34:46Z` and print it as `03/15/10 at 4:34PM`

Comment: @Sheehan Alam sorry, I mixed this with another question I've answered - see my update again.

Comment: `2010-03-15T16:34:46Z` throws an ParsableException unparceable date -- see updated code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format output string, change following line in your code

```
dateText.setText(date.toString());
```

to

```
dateText.setText(String.format("%1$tm/%1$td/%1$ty at %1$tl:%1$tM%1$Tp", date));
```