# Smart time calculation

Tags: java, android, date

I'm looking for some standard and algorithm (may be library) to present when some event happens. What I mean - fo ex. if someone post message 2 minutes ago - I want to display "2 min ago" instead full date and time "12-sep-13 5:17 PM".  Then after hour - "An hour ago" ...

I want to know may be exist some standard - for ex. "2 days ago" - it's correct, but instead "3 days ago" I must display full date.

May be some one knows some library or use own elegant algorithm.
 If you share it - will be helpful.(I don't want to reinvent the bicycle)

Comment: This type of question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow... Maybe Google could help you out?

Comment: Can't you check the timestamp difference and round it to minutes ?

Comment: @TheNickmaster21 - I ask about existing android-style standard. Does this is't SO question type?  ps. already check google

Comment: Would love to have such a library. One of the harder parts in reinventing the bicycle is localization since date & time information differs a lot in different languages.

Comment: @alfasin, yes - all algorithms based on it, but where is the line between short label and full date?

Comment: This is an opinion based question. You're just asking people to find you a library. There are better places and proper places to ask things like this.

Comment: @zapl - really?  A localize date - is simple, I guess.

Comment: @TheNickmaster21 first of all, I ask about existing standard. Secondary - about realization of that standard. Sorry if I incorrect presents my ideas.

Comment: " I'm looking for some standard and algorithm"?

Comment: @TheNickmaster21 it seems to me that you were too easy on the trigger, check out the first 4 bullet points here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic his question is totally legit.

Comment: @TheNickmaster21 Oh.... STANDARD and algorithm...

Comment: @jimpanzer "2 days ago" vs "Vor 2 Tagen" (.de) requires at least different formatting. Then localization for "day" vs "days", .. and there are maybe even other more complex differences in other languages that require country specific rules to create a "2 days ago" equivalent. (e.g. "yesterday" instead of "1 day ago" might have no equivalent in other languages). Printing a localized full date is not a problem.

Comment: @zapl, sorry, I thought of another. But that problem - also has a solution. I can build the final version of the library with correct resource file by myself.

Comment: I like this question I've bookmarked it for later reference when I need to look at it "10 days from now".

Comment: Take a look at [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen, thanks. May be this is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time)
 and this lib ([JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)). This lib is not small but maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I checked both links. Maybe this is the best what I saw. But no words about standard. If no one post better answer - I accept yours