# Compare current date-time [timestamp] with date-time chosen from a calendar dialog and display in user understandable way

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I would like to display a set of user understandable date-time formats when user selects a date-time from a calendar dialog.

For ex:

1. I don't choose a date a default current timestamp is formatted and displayed. In place of a date time that says "May 09th, 2014 07:40 AM" I want the textview to display "Now".
2. If I select the time from the calendar dialog as "08:00 AM" (wrt to 07:00 AM current time), I should display as "in another 1 hour".
3. And anything more than a day would say "Date - Time" (Existing format).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smart time calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766926/smart-time-calculation). That Question has an answer that links to [prettytime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the same thing recently by using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

By using this you can get the Time difference in different formats. sample code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 09);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
Date startDate = cal.getTime();

//Use JodaTime to calculate difference
Period period =  getTimePassedSince(startDate);

//Extract values and display
long days= Math.abs(period.getDays()));
long hours= Math.abs(period.getHours()));
long minitues =Math.abs(period.getMinutes()));
long secnds =Math.abs(period.getSeconds()));

...
public static Period getTimePassedSince(Date initialTimestamp){
        DateTime initDT = new DateTime(initialTimestamp.getTime());
        DateTime now = new DateTime();
        Period p = new Period(initDT, now, PeriodType.dayTime()).normalizedStandard( PeriodType.dayTime());
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Calendar class on purpose here? If not, you can use Joda-Time for that portion as well: `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 2014, DateTimeConstants.MAY, 9, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );`

Comment: FYI, rather than pull out the days, hours, and such into integers from which to build text, you can use a built-in Joda-Time feature: [PeriodFormatterBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html). Example code to get something like "15 years and 8 months"… 

 `PeriodFormatter yearsAndMonths = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
     .printZeroAlways()
     .appendYears()
     .appendSuffix(" year", " years")
     .appendSeparator(" and ")
     .printZeroRarelyLast()
     .appendMonths()
     .appendSuffix(" month", " months")
     .toFormatter();`

Comment: You can pass a java.util.Date directly to a DateTime constructor. No need for `.getTime()`. Like this: `DateTime initDT = new DateTime( initialTimestamp );`

Comment: Thank you Leena and Basil. That helped me a lot. I used the code shared by Leena and it worked like a charm! :)