# Store numerical value in form of HH:MM (Not time)

Tags: java, variables, date, types

I need to figure out how to store times like `12:45, 13:45` etc.. so in format of `HH:MM`
It is NOT NECESSARY to use date functionality in java, these will not be used to time an event or anything of that matter, all I need them for is to perform operations like `13:45 - 12:45` and get output which in this case is `01:00` I tried doing this with doubles, however ran into issue of something like `13.45 + 00.35 = 13.80;` as there are only 60 minutes in a hour, expected output should be `14.20`

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with date as well, but remember at the moment I do not need to be concerned about things like time zones, calendar dates etc.. I need to figure out how to make numbers behave like hours and minutes.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: If you want numbers to behave like times, treat them as such. Then you won't have to bother with wrapping around 60 and stuff like that.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That's totally what I just wrote, but you were faster ;-)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel could you expand on your comment, as now even if I treat a double like 12.30 as a time adding lets say 45 minutes, so 00.45 to it will result in 12.75, and that is not time at all, I probably don't get the idea just yet.

Comment: @ilya: just create two dates and use those objects (`Calendar`). You don't care about the date aspect, just the time.

Comment: "there are only 60 minutes in a hour" = The reason you should time data as time rather than as decimal numbers. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) provides the time-based objects you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's my comment written out:

```
Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 05, 05, 12, 40, 0);
Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 05, 05, 12, 15, 0);

Calendar diff = end - start;
int minutes = diff.get(Calendar.Minutes);
int seconds = diff.get(Calendar.Seconds);
```

You don't have to use the date part to use the time part.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an object. Call it HHMM. It would look something like this

```
public class HHMM {

  private int HH;
  private int MM;

  public HHMM(HH, MM) {

    this.HH = HH
    this.MM = MM

  }

  public toStr() {
    return HH + ":" + MM
  }

  public minus(HHMM hhmm){
    //write code here that subtracts the passed HHMM from this HHMM
  }

  //make a plus method too, and any other methods, etc.


}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) has already implemented what you are looking for in the [LocalTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class:

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("12:45");
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("13:45");
Period period = new Period(start, end);
```

and

```
LocalTime start = new LocalTime(13, 45);
LocalTime later = start.plusMinutes(35);
```

Comment: Correct answer by matsev. With a Period object in hand, you can calculate elapsed time. See [How to calculate elapsed time from now with Joda Time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time).

Answer (score 0):

Store all numbers in minutes then. Using a single integer, you can do simple time manipulation by doing integer math. Mod all your operations by 1440 (60*24) if you don't care about what day it is:

Example:

```
int time = 600;

//Example time operation
time = (5000 + time) % 1440; //Day-insensitve

//Perform this check if you suspect time will become negative.
if(time < 0){
    time = 1440 + time;
}

//Display time
int hours = time / 60; //Integer division of 60, get the maximum number of "perfect 60s" in your time component.
int minutes = time % 60; //Integer mod, get the remainder since the last "perfect 60"

System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes));
```

Note how most time keeping constructs simply store time/date or whatever as a single numerical value with a base unit. Take for example: `System.currentTimeMillis()` which returns time as a number of milliseconds since the epoch.

If you require only simple manipulation operations with something like time, you need only understand how to parse a single value into your desired components (e.g seconds, minutes, hours). Operations on this numerical value is same like traditional mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

One way I use to make transactions with date and hours in java, I use a framework, called [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), he is very good. Only you just download the. Jar, and looks at the ways how to do operations with més, years and days. Using this framework vc saves a lot of headaches by doing more complex codes.