# Joda Time does not take AM/PM into account when using hours between, and 12 hour time not working

Tags: java, eclipse, datetime, jodatime

I am writing a program to calculate age difference in java using Joda Time, and when calculating hoursBetween(), it does not take into account AM and PM. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String DOB = "";
    String NOW = "";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa");

    Date dob = null;
    Date now = null;

    try {

        System.out
                .println("Enter the date and time of your birth using the mm/dd/yyyy and the hh:mm AM/PM format: ");
        DOB = scan.nextLine();

        System.out
                .println("Enter the date and time using the mm/dd/yyyy and the hh:mm AM/PM format: ");
        NOW = scan.nextLine();

        dob = format.parse(DOB);
        now = format.parse(NOW);

        DateTime dob1 = new DateTime(dob);
        DateTime now1 = new DateTime(now);



        System.out.print("You are ");
        System.out.print(Years.yearsBetween(dob1, now1).getYears()
                + " years, ");
        System.out.print(Months.monthsBetween(dob1, now1).getMonths() % 12
                + " months, ");
        System.out.print(Days.daysBetween(dob1, now1).getDays() % 60
                + " days, ");
        System.out.print(Hours.hoursBetween(dob1, now1).getHours() % 12
                + " hours, ");
        System.out.print("and "
                + Minutes.minutesBetween(dob1, now1).getMinutes() % 60
                + " minutes old!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

If my input for date of birth is "01/01/2014 12:00 AM" and my input for the current time is "01/01/2014 12:00 PM" the result is: "You are 0 years, 0 months, 0 hours, and 0 minutes old." When it should be 12 hours old. Is there a way to fix this? My guess is there is some way to implement the halfdayOfDay() method and invoke it on my **DateTime**'s, but I haven't found it...Thanks for any help!(By the way, I am using 12 hour day's for input, but while parsing it still accepts 13:00, when it should max out at 12:00!)

Comment: Why use `SimpleDateFormat` instead of Joda's built-in `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: I am new to joda, and did not know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing modulo 12 on the number of hours between

```
Hours.hoursBetween(dob1, now1).getHours() % 12
```

So

```
12 % 12 = 0
```

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Comment: @user2756173 What are you trying to do with the modulo?

Comment: Thank you, I use it so that it isn't redundant between months and years (ex. 1 year, 12 months old)! Did not realize how this affected the program

Comment: But do you know how to avoid allowing users to allow over 12:00? Thank you

Comment: @user2756173 There is no such built-in feature as far as I know.

Comment: Also, I am now using % 24, and an automatic DateTime for the current time, and it works! Thank you for helping me; this is one of my first java programs that I have completed.

Answer (score 0):

You are working too hard.

Joda-Time provides classes to do exactly this work: [`PeriodFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html) and [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html).

See [this answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179831/642706).

That answer shows you code like this:

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" seconds ago\n")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minutes ago\n")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hours ago\n")
    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" days ago\n")
    .appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" weeks ago\n")
    .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" months ago\n")
    .appendYears().appendSuffix(" years ago\n")
    .printZeroNever()
    .toFormatter();
```